# what is the performance btw two-way broadcasting and video conferencing

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, rtcmulticonnection

two-way video broadcasting is where users can see broadcaster and broadcaster can see user but users should not interact with other users.

video conference like every one interact.

what will be the performance difference if use [RTCMulticonnection](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection)

As described documentation in [one-to-multiple video broadcasting](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/broadcast)

Multi-ports establishment causes huge CPU and bandwidth usage!
If 10 users join your broadcasted room, 40 RTP ports will be opened on your browser:

```
10 RTP ports for outgoing audio streams
10 RTP ports for outgoing video streams
10 RTP ports for incoming audio streams
10 RTP ports for incoming video streams
```

what happens if 100 users join Broadcast. I mean the performance of the device and what bandwidth it requires if I go with

```
 480 x 360 (360p)
 858 x 480 (480p)
 1280 x 720 (720p)
```

and the same for the videoconference

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you can just look up online how much bandwidth 360p uses with webrtc and multiply by the amount of streams.

Comment: By the way a better solution would be to use an SFU (Selective Fowarding Unit)

Comment: @DirkV thanks for your valuable response. I read about bandwidth usage but I want to know the performance of the browser. As I mentioned in question in two-way broadcast for 10 users 40 RTP ports opened from broadcasters end 4 from users. if this in the case of the conference will it be 40 ports opens from every user's end. and if yes then how will be the browser's performance? and what would be the system requeirements interms of ram, processor. for both user and server ends.

Comment: the performance cpu is not a bandwidth issue but more an encoding issue. as you will need to encode your video for every stream. There aren't many benchmarks for the cpu so I think you'll have test yourself.